# How to filter datagridview using two datetimepicker in C# with firebird database?

Tags: c#, firebird

I am using C# in Visual Studio 2012, `firebird` is my database.

what is the code in searching and displaying a range of date in `DataGridView`?
my database procedure is possibly wrong. Pls fix this line of code of my procedure.

```
 CREATE PROCEDURE LEAVETRANS_DATESRCH(
  BEGIN_DAY SMALLINT,
  BEGIN_MONTH SMALLINT,
  BEGIN_YEAR SMALLINT,
  END_DAY SMALLINT,
  END_MONTH SMALLINT,
  END_YEAR SMALLINT)
RETURNS(
  LEAVETRANS_EMPNAME VARCHAR(50) CHARACTER SET ISO8859_1 COLLATE ISO8859_1,
  LEAVETRANS_LEAVENAME VARCHAR(50) CHARACTER SET ISO8859_1 COLLATE ISO8859_1,
  LEAVETRANS_DAYS DECIMAL(12, 2),
  LEAVETRANS_TIME TIME,
  LEAVETRANS_REASON VARCHAR(500) CHARACTER SET ISO8859_1 COLLATE ISO8859_1)
AS
BEGIN
  FOR
    SELECT
      LEAVETRANS_EMPNAME,
      LEAVETRANS_LEAVENAME,
      LEAVETRANS_DAYS,
      LEAVETRANS_TIME,
      LEAVETRANS_REASON

    FROM LEAVETRANSACTION WHERE LT_DAY =:BEGIN_DAY AND LT_MONTH =:BEGIN_MONTH
    AND LT_YEAR =:BEGIN_YEAR OR LT_DAY =:END_DAY AND LT_MONTH =:END_MONTH AND LT_YEAR 
    =:END_YEAR
    INTO

      :LEAVETRANS_EMPNAME,
      :LEAVETRANS_LEAVENAME,
      :LEAVETRANS_DAYS,
      :LEAVETRANS_TIME,
      :LEAVETRANS_REASON

  DO
    BEGIN
      SUSPEND;
    END
END;
```

Comment: What is `textBox1.Text`? Where is your `DateTimePicker`? Please show us more code

Comment: here is the procedure of my database. I find out that i cannot get the correct filtered  range dates in this line of codes.  Please Help.. I need to get the in between dates      ..                                                                                                                                                                                                FROM LEAVETRANSACTION WHERE LT_DAY =:BEGIN_DAY AND LT_MONTH =:BEGIN_MONTH
    AND LT_YEAR =:BEGIN_YEAR OR LT_DAY =:END_DAY AND LT_MONTH =:END_MONTH AND LT_YEAR 
    =:END_YEAR INTO

Comment: Ohhh please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. This is impossible to read your code